# Windows 7 can't ping an IP

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, ping

I am unable to ping an IP address on a Amazon EC2 instance. When I do it from a Mac or Linux machine, it works just fine. But, on Windows 7 it doesn't work.

I've tried turning off the firewall, but that doesn't seem to work either. Pinging any other site like www.google.com or Mac.com works fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: When you try to ping, does it timeout?

Comment: yes it times out

Comment: Is the IP sensitive, can you give it to us to try?

Comment: what happens when you do a tracert on the IP?

Comment: Have you tried to use the "tracert" to trace the route to see where it's exactly timing out?

Comment: Yes, I doesn't find anything at all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That seems odd, ICMP is disabled by default on the firewall to your ec2 instance. Try running this command on your ec2 instance's firewall security group:

```
ec2-authorize default -P icmp -t -1:-1 -s 0.0.0.0/0
```

See the EC2 [FAQ Article](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1145#18) regarding ICMP.

Comment: Also, I was using some kind of "internal" up address, as opposed to an external ip address. I don't understand why it wasn't an issue on the posix machines.

Comment: @maximus you're most welcome